# How to schedule r and python script on unix server used by many users in a centralized way

Tags: python, r, unix, scheduling

I am finalizing a new Unix Server with R/Rstudio Server and Python/ANAconda/Jupyter Lab to be able to let users (kinda 15 end-user of different skill levels) run self analysis, save output and maybe schedule some job and run.

I need a way to schedule R and python script and job (the best would be a single tool that can handle both) in a easy and trasparent way (so also the low-level skill users could use it) that it is centralized for all the users that get access to it.

I have seen cronR for R but it seems to be for single users and not centralizable.

There is a way or maybe some other open source tool that can be used so to make transparent scheduling ?
Ideally the scheduling will be time-based, but also trigger/event based.

What firewall port, bash abilitation and command should i have installed and configured?

Comment: Apache Airflow allows to do trigger/event based scheduling: http://airflow.apache.org. You can launch R processes with the bashoperator. But it might be a bit intimidating for basic users as they need to specify their schedules in Python scripts.

Comment: What do you mean specify the schedule in the script? I do not know the tools you have linked ... It is possible to schedule different language scripts (such as python, r) ? it has a UI even on Unix machine ? 8accessible via web browser?)

Comment: Yes, you can schedule R and Python or bash or whichever language you like. It has a UI, accessible with the web browser. Schedules should be written as Python scripts. The learning curve will be steeper compared to cronR for example due to this.